# java - How do I find the extents of an object within a BufferedImage

Tags: java, bufferedimage

So I am trying to find the upper, lower, left and right extents of an object in a png image. The image has a transparent background and a black circle in the middle. How do I find the upper, lower, left and right extents of the circle (which is completely black) thus isolating the circle from the transparent background?

What I tried so far:

```
    public static BufferedImage trimImage(BufferedImage image) {
    int left = 0, right = 0, up = 0, down = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i<image.getHeight(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<image.getWidth(); j++) {
            if(image.getRGB(j, i)==0) {
                up = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i<image.getWidth(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<image.getHeight(); j++) {
            if(image.getRGB(i, j)==0) {
                left = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i<image.getHeight(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<image.getWidth(); j++) {
            if(image.getRGB(j, i)==0&&i>down) {
                down = i;
            }
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i<image.getWidth(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<image.getHeight(); j++) {
            if(image.getRGB(i, j)==0&&i>down) {
                right = i;
            }
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println(up+","+down+","+left+","+right);
    BufferedImage temp = image.getSubimage(left, up, right-left, down-up);
    return temp;
}
```

Do you know a simpler method? This gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (x + width) is outside raster
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

edit: Here's the complete stackTrace():

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (x + width) is outside raster
at sun.awt.image.IntegerInterleavedRaster.createWritableChild(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getSubimage(Unknown Source)
at main.ImageHandler.trimLetter(ImageHandler.java:114)
at main.HandwritingReader.<init>(HandwritingReader.java:48)
at main.HandwritingReader.main(HandwritingReader.java:55)
```

Comment: Where does the exception come from? Can you please add the complete stack trace? And I would replace x for i on the x axis and y for j on the y axis. :)

Comment: Yes I did indeed try to change the places of x and y, also the other way round, swapping both, and also getWidth() and getHeight(). Does not work. Here's the stack trace:

Exception in thread "main" 
java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (x + width) is outside raster
 at sun.awt.image.IntegerInterleavedRaster.createWritableChild(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getSubimage(Unknown Source)
 at main.ImageHandler.trimLetter(ImageHandler.java:114)
 at main.HandwritingReader.<init>(HandwritingReader.java:48)
 at main.HandwritingReader.main(HandwritingReader.java:55)

Comment: You stack trace does belong to an other class you did not mention.

Comment: The only thing I am doing from the other  class is calling this function for an image. This is the only reference to this function: for(int i = 0; i<296; i++) {
   BufferedImage temp = ImageHandler.trimImage(letters.get(i));
   letters.set(i, temp);
  }................... Letters is an ArrayList containing the images

Comment: You could do this with one nested loop. It looks like your first two nested loops are 'ok' but the second two have a fault in logic.

Comment: These are my up, down, left, and right values: 159,159,123,0. They are horribly wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that the left is the lowest x coordinate, top is the lowest y coordinate, right is the highest x coordinate and bottom is the highest y coordinate.

```
int left = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int right = 0;
int top = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int bottom = 0;

for(int i = 0; i<image.getWidth(); i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j<image.getHeight(); j++) {
        if(image.getRGB(i, j)==0) {
            left = Math.min(left, i);
            right = Math.max(right, i);
            top = Math.min(top, j);
            bottom = Math.max(bottom, j);
        }
    }
}
```

That should give you the bounds when the loop completes.

I made an example image and tried it out.

```
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(256, 256, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(25, 25, 32, 32);
        g.dispose();
```

In this case, I had to check if `image.getRGB() != 0` because the transparent pixels are 0, but the black pixels have 255 alpha value.